# Azure Resource Manager on behalf of Azure AD Multitenant App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

### General Overview of what I am trying to achieve

I am trying to build an Azure AD Multitenant Web application which allows me to manage resources in customer subscriptions/tenants using the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) APIs. I am pretty new to Azure AD Multitenancy.

### The Ideal control flow

```
1. A customer browses the Applications (ideal an admin of the customer tenant)
2. Will be granted with Azure AD authorize flow 
3. Accepts everything and grants admin consent for the AD App in their tenant
4. Unclear: The AD App will be granted contributer access on a subscription or resource
5. My Web App will be able to use the AD App credentials to manage the customer resources using the ARM APIs
```

### Problem

**Steps 1-3, 5**: Are clear and I know how to build that.
**Step 4**: I am not sure how to build that so that step happens automatically.

### Solutions I have considered

The worst case would be the customer AD Admin must manually grant the AD App access to a subscription or resource using the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that came to my mind is that you require the user_impersonation permission on Azure Service Management API.
After the user logs in, you could list out the subscriptions available, allowing the user to select one.
Then list out the resource groups if needed.

Once the user confirms a selection, your app could add itself as a Contributor on the targeted resource through the Management API, on behalf of the currently signed-in user.

To do this, you will need the object id of the service principal for your app created in the target tenant. 
You can get it by acquiring an app-only token for e.g. the Azure Management API from that tenant's token endpoint after the user has logged in. 
The token will contain an oid claim, which is the object id for the service principal.

Of course the user who signs in would have to have the ability to modify access to the target resource.

I would say the downside of this approach is that the organization must trust your app to only do the thing it claims to do.
The approach where they grant the access manually allows them to be in control fully.

Comment: I haven’t thought about that. I will try that, thank you!

Comment: I have now implemented this approach and it works great, the only problem I currently have is that the Azure RBAC API Endpoint needs the **Object Id** of the Enterprise Application / Service Principal which gets created in the remote tenant as the Application Id doesn't work. And I'm not sure how to query the Object Id.

Comment: Ahhh that is true :\ I'll have to check the documentation and see if there is an easy way to get it.

Comment: Found a solution by looking at the API requests the azure cli makes. Turns out you can query it using the `graph.windows.net` API.     
`https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals?$filter=servicePrincipalNames/any(c:c eq '{appClientId}')&api-version=1.6`

Comment: Ahh, that's Azure AD Graph API. I recommend you check out if Microsoft Graph API (graph.microsoft.com) can do the same for you. AAD Graph API is being deprecated currently. Which endpoint are you using there?

Comment: Looking at the Microsoft Graph API it seems like this doesn't provide the data I would need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
   
(Also edited my previous comment to include the endpoint)

Comment: Hmm... A thought came to my mind. After the tenant has consented to your app, a service principal is created in their tenant right? Well, that enables you to get app-only tokens for any API in that tenant, even with no permissions. If you ask for an app-only token to e.g. Azure Management API, it should contain the object id of your app in their tenant.

Comment: Then you won't have to query any API for it.